# Can not figure out how Stanford Dependencies works

Tags: java, dependencies, nlp, stanford-nlp

My task is to parse text and find out the main characters in sentences. I need a Stanford Dependencies Parser, but i can't figure out, how and where can i get it. I downloaded CoreNLP as SD is a part of it. What should I do next? Didn't find any tutorials about how SDP works.
I will be very grateful if someone explains me, what i should do.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run CoreNLP with the following command to generate dependency parses for all the sentences in `INPUT.txt`. Make sure that you are running this from the CoreNLP directory or otherwise adjust the classpath (`-cp`)

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP \
  -annotators "tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse" -file INPUT.txt -outputFormat conllu
```

This will parse your sentences to [English Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/) (a newer dependency representation, based on Stanford Dependencies) and output them in [CoNLL-U format](http://universaldependencies.org/format.html).

If you want to parse the sentences to the old Stanford Dependencies representation, use the following command.

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP \
  -annotators "tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse" -file INPUT.txt -outputFormat conllu\
  -depparse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/PTB_Stanford_params.txt.gz
```

You can find more information on how to run CoreNLP on the [CoreNLP website.](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/)